# Decomposition of characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a linear transformation on an n-dimensional linear space on a domain F，if a linear space V has a direct sum decomposition$$V=U\oplus W $$W and U are invariant subspaces of A.
Is the characteristic polynomial of A the product of the constraint of A on U and the constraint of A on W?

Comment: Yes because the determinant of a diagonal block matrix is the product of the determinants of the blocks.

Comment: Nice, I understand. Thank you.